# Find equation of the tangent line at $\pi/3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the equation of the tangent line to $f′(x) = 4 \sin x + 3 \cos x$ at $x=  π/3$. I'm trying to incorporate the slope point formula.

#### Progress

This is what I got: $f'(x)= 4 \cos x- 3 \sin x$ at $x= π/3$, $$f(π/3)= 4 \cos π/3 - 3 \sin π/3 = 4(1/2)-3(\sqrt{3}/2) = ?? $$

Comment: If you want the tangent line to $f'(x)$ at $x$ then take the derivative of $f'(x)$. The slope is $f''(\frac{\pi}{3})$

Comment: It's the straight line with slope $f'(\pi / 3)$ that goes through $(\pi/3, f(\pi/3)$ - just work those quantities out and plug it all into the formula for a straight line.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! People are ready to help you but show your efforts, describe what you tried and tell where you are stuck. Cheers :-)

Comment: tangent line to $f$ or to $f'$?

Comment: it is tangent line to f

Comment: This is what i got
f'(x)= 4 cos x- 3 sin x    at   x=  π/3  
f(π/3)= 4 cos π/3 - 3 sin π/3 =  4(1/2)-3(√3/2)  = ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will get
$f''(x)=4\cos(x)-3\sin(x)$
and 
$f''(\pi/3)=2\sqrt{3}+\frac{3}{2}$
further we have
$f'(\pi/3)=\frac{3}{2}+2\sqrt{3}$
and you can calculate the tangent line
$y=mx+n$
Sonnhard.